# Why Alamofire is using dispatch_sync() function when creating a dataTask?

Tags: alamofire

The code below is from source code of [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create(nil, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

public func request(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> Request {
    var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask!
    dispatch_sync(queue) { dataTask = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(URLRequest.URLRequest) }

    let request = Request(session: session, task: dataTask)
    self.delegate[request.delegate.task] = request.delegate

    if startRequestsImmediately {
        request.resume()
    }

    return request
}
```

It seems like every time it creates a dataTask, it dispatch that creating process to a serial queue. Would this measure protect the program from any kind of multi-thread trap?

I can't figure out what's the difference without that queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why we implemented that check is due to Alamofire [Issue #393](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/393). We were seeing duplicate task identifiers without the serial queue when creating data and upload tasks in parallel from multiple threads. It appears that Apple has a thread safety issue when incrementing the task identifiers. Therefore in Alamofire, we eliminate the issue by creating the tasks on a serial queue.

Cheers.